# When the function f is constant?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a differential function. Let $Df(x)$ be the derivative of $f$ at $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Then which of the following is(/are)  correct?

1. $Df(0)(u) = 0$ for all $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$
2. $Df(x)(u) = 0$ for all $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and some $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ only if $f$ is a constant.
3. $Df(x)(u) = 0$ for all $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and all $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ only if $f$ is a constant.
4. If $f$ is not a constant function, then $Df(x)$ is a one to one function for some $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

I can see that option $1$ is wrong but I can not understand how to proceed for remaining 3 options. Please help.

Comment: What's the correct reading of 2.? Is it $\forall u\exists x(Df(x))(u)=0$ or $\exists x\forall u(Df(x))(u)=0$?

Comment: I may be dense, but I do not understand what $Df(0)(u)$ means. $f$ and $Df$ are functions $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, $Df(0)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$, but what is $Df(0)(u)$? Is it an inner product?

Comment: @RoryDaulton $Df$ is a function, which makes $(Df)(0)$ a function itself. **Edit:** I misused the term *functional*, $(Df)(0)$ is a linear map.

Comment: @GitGud: I get it now. I *was* dense! I forgot the definition of the derivative of a multivariable, multidimensional function.

Comment: $(Df)(0)(u)$ means the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $0$ in the direction $u$.

Comment: Try the function $f(x,y)=(x^2,0)$. It should tell you about the truth of some more statements.

Comment: This example says that option (2) and (3) are false..but (4) ?